# Where are the Configurations made in OSGi Console saved?

Tags: osgi, aem, apache-felix, aem-6

When we update any configuration for a component in the Configurations tab in the Apache Felix Web OSGi Console, where are these configuration settings saved? This is with respect to AEM 6.0 or above.

Answer (score 14):

The manually saved configuration settings are stored in the the `crx-quickstart/launchpad/config` directory (in your AEM installation folder in the local file system) and, on top of that, as `.config` files in the Content Respository at `/apps/system/config`.

For example, if you're looking for the configuration of `com.example.MyComponent`, you can find it as a text file in `crx-quickstart/launchpad/config/com/example/MyComponent.config` (in the local file system) and at `/apps/system/config/com.example.MyComponent.config` inside your Content Repository.

The files at these two locations are updated when you change the settings manually in the OSGi console.

In AEM you can also store configuration in JCR nodes of the type `sling:OsgiConfig`. These will not be created or updated when you manually save the config but they offer a neat way of managing configuration as content.

When AEM looks for the configuration, the following order of resolution is used:

1. nodes under `/apps/*/config`, be it property files or JCR nodes with the node `jcr:primaryType` of `sling:OsgiConfig`
2. nodes with type `sling:OsgiConfig` under `/libs/*/config`, these are OOTB definitions for components that come with AEM
3. `.config files` from `<aem-installation-directory>/crx-quickstart/launchpad/config/` on the local file system.

Depending on the OSGi configuration of *Apache Sling JCR Installer*, the `sling:OsgiConfig` nodes can be written back to when you manually change the config. There's also a number of settings affecting the lookup of said configurations so it's a good idea to familiarise oneself with this config.

Please check out the [official documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/deploy/configuring/configuring-osgi.html) for more comprehensive information.

If you're trying to get a config stored in a `sling:OsgiConfig` node to work as expected and you're unsure if another config for the same service has been cached somewhere, here's a sequence of steps that has worked for me consistently in AEM 6.4:

1. Delete the `sling:OsgiConfig` node you just created
2. Go to the Felix console's `configMgr`, find the relevant service and *Delete* the configuration.
3. Recreate the `sling:OsgiConfig` node (I usually keep those in a CRX package that I can simply reinstall)

Answer (score 1):

The configurations are stored by the felix configadmin bundle inside the felix bundle cache. Not sure where this cache is located in AEM. In Apache Karaf the configs in my case are in:

```
data/cache/bundle7/date/config
```

Where bundle id 7 is the id of the configadmin bundle.