# Disable AEM's ink checker using cURL

Tags: curl, osgi, aem

As per this article - https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/DisableLinkChecker.html to disable link checker in AEM we need to follow these steps -

**Disable all link checking by configuration**

1. Go to /system/console/configMgr and login as admin.
2. Find the "Link Checker Transformer"
3. Check the "Disable Checking" box and save
4. Go to /crx/explorer and login as admin
5. Open "Content Explorer"
6. Browse to /var/linkchecker
7. Right click the node and select "Delete Recursively"
8. Click "Save All"

I want to include disabling link checker as a part of my AEM server's deployment/setup script. Is there a way to do this using cURL?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Steps 1 to 4

To check the `Disable Checking` box using cURL, this should do the trick:

```
curl -u admin:admin http://localhost:4502/system/console/configMgr/com.day.cq.rewriter.linkchecker.impl.LinkCheckerTransformerFactory --data 
"apply=true&action=ajaxConfigManager&%24location=launchpad%3Aresources%2Finstall%2F0%2Fcq-rewriter-5.9.30.jar&linkcheckertransformer.disableRewriting=false&linkcheckertransformer.disableChecking=true&linkcheckertransformer.mapCacheSize=5000&linkcheckertransformer.strictExtensionCheck=false&linkcheckertransformer.stripHtmltExtension=false&linkcheckertransformer.rewriteElements=a%3Ahref&linkcheckertransformer.rewriteElements=area%3Ahref&linkcheckertransformer.rewriteElements=form%3Aaction&propertylist=linkcheckertransformer.disableRewriting%2Clinkcheckertransformer.disableChecking%2Clinkcheckertransformer.mapCacheSize%2Clinkcheckertransformer.strictExtensionCheck%2Clinkcheckertransformer.stripHtmltExtension%2Clinkcheckertransformer.rewriteElements"
```

I used firefox network tab (firebug) to capture the above payload. You can do this as well, just check the box and hit save in configMgr and capture the corresponding network req. There is an option to `Edit and Resend` a request, click that and you'll see the url encoded request body.

---

Better way to do this -

The above cURL updates the field in configMgr (applies to the entire server) and is generally not recommended.

Instead create a run mode config and modify this field there. This cURL should help you with that. This creates a `sling:OsgiConfig` node under your apps `config` node.

```
curl  -F "jcr:primaryType=sling:OsgiConfig"  -F linkcheckertransformer.disableChecking=true -F "linkcheckertransformer.disableChecking@TypeHint=Boolean" -u admin:admin  http://localhost:4502/apps/<<YOUR_APP>>/config/com.day.cq.rewriter.linkchecker.impl.LinkCheckerTransformerFactory
```

---

- Steps 5 to 8

`curl -u admin:admin -X DELETE http://localhost:4502/var/linkchecker`

Comment: When i run curl  -F "jcr:primaryType=sling:OsgiConfig"  -F linkcheckertransformer.disableChecking=true -F "linkcheckertransformer.disableChecking@TypeHint=Boolean" -u admin:admin  http://localhost:4502/apps/system/config/com.day.cq.rewriter.linkchecker.impl.LinkCheckerTransformerFactory it creates a node under "config". How do you check whether the linkchecker has actually been disabled? Please note that i created this node under /system/config

Comment: If you created this under `/system/config` it'll be stored in your filesystem, under `/crx-quickstart/launchpad/config`. Check this post for more details on location of osgi configs -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/42340483/4173416